# How can I build a counter with a database to persist the value in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, faunadb

I am building a `like-counter` in a `NextJS` `ReactJS` app, which stores a persistent incrementable `count` value. The `max-count` of `clicks` / `likes` is to be set to `100`. The `button` will not increment the `count` any further than this value. The `like-counter` value is stored in a **[FaunaDB](https://fauna.com)**.

I can render the value stored in the `db` on the front-end, but I can't get the `onClick` handler to *update* the value stored in the `db`.

Here is the (commented) `code` so far:

Here, `State` is declared via a `useState` hook.

```
const [likes, setLikes] = useState([]);
```

The updateLikes function

```
async function updateLikes() {
   await fetch("/api/newLikes", requestOptionsLikes)
      .then(() => getLikes())
      .catch((e) => console.log(e))
}
```

The `PUT` method is instantiated:

```
  const requestOptionsLikes = {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ likes })
  }
```

A useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
   getLikes();
   }, []);
```

The click function:

```
const handleSubmitLikes = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   updateLikes();
  }
```

The `JSX` that renders the clickable `LIKE` button and displays the value from the `db`.

```
<div>
   <div onClick={handleSubmitLikes}>LIKE</div>
      </div>
      {
        likes.map((d) => (
          <div>
            <div>{d.data.like}</div>
          </div>
      ))}
</div>
```

The code is correctly fetching the `likes` from the DB so I think that there is no need to display the `getLikes` `API`. However the `newLikes` `API` is returning a 500 Internal Server Error, so I display it below:

```
const faunadb = require("faunadb");

// your secret hash
const secret = process.env.FAUNADB_SECRET_KEY;
const q = faunadb.query;
const client = new faunadb.Client({ secret });

console.log("CALLLED API")

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const formData = req.body.data;
  console.log("API CALL");
  try {
    const dbs = await client.query(
      console.log("API UPDATE"),
      console.log(formData),

      q.Update(
        q.Ref(q.Collection('Likes'), '305446225474224651'),
        {
          data: {
            like: formData.likes[0].data.like + 1
          },
        }
      )
    );
    // ok
    res.status(200).json(dbs.data);
  } catch (e) {
    // something went wrong
    res.status(500).json({ error: e.message });
  }
};
```

Basically, I can't update the Database via the PUT method.

Comment: Is `console.log(formData)` displaying the expected output?

Comment: Hi. Basically no. It cannot find the variable. Basically, I think the error (so far) is with the call to `await fetch("/api/newLikes", requestOptionsLikes)`.  It returns a 500, but even if I set a console.log within the getLikes API call (as edited above as console.log("API CALL")), it fails to register on console.

Comment: Make sure to look for `console.log("API CALL")` in the terminal where you started the Next.js server and not in the browser's console. Do you still not see it there?

Comment: Yes! I see it there. It's in the browser console - both the console.log("CALLED API") and the console.log("API CALL").

Comment: However `console.log(formData)` is returning "undefined". I think it mean the `PUT` query is improperly specified. I don't think the 'code' is 'asking' the database to update the value of like - it's currently set to `3` in the `db`.

Comment: What's the output of logging `e` in the `catch` block of your API route? If `formData` is undefined then this line `like: formData.like + 1` will error.

Comment: The output in the browser is: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`. There is no other error message - either in browser or in the terminal.

Comment: Try replacing your `formatData` declaration with: `const formData = req.body;`.

Comment: Great idea. `console.log(formData.likes)` returns the following output in the terminal: `[ { ref: { '@ref': [Object] },ts: __ref_code__, data: { like: 3 } }]`. If I `console.log(formData.likes.data.like)` however, it returns no output to the console.

Comment: This string: `formData.likes.data.like + 1` is failing to increment the value in the database.

Comment: `formData.likes` is an array, if you want to access the first item you need to do so with `formData.likes[0].data.like`

Comment: Yep that accesses the correct value: If I `console.log(formData.likes[0].data.like + 1)`, then I receive `4`, however, within the Update function `data: { like: formData.likes[0].data.like + 1, },` is not rendering an update to the `db` value - neither is: `like: like + 1`.

Comment: Any ideas how to update the like count from within the Update query?

Answer (score 2):

Your demonstrated code appears to increment that value provided in the PUT request, which potentially allows the current client to specify any value. There is also no evidence that you are capping the count at 100.

You can perform the counter increment entirely in FQL with a query like this:

```
q.Let(
  {
    counterRef: q.Ref(q.Collection('Likes'), '305446225474224651'),
    counterDoc: q.Get(q.Var('counterRef'),
    counterVal: q.Select(['data', 'like'], q.Var('counterDoc')
    newCounterVal: q.If(
      q.GTE(q.Var('counterVal'), 100),
      100,
      q.Add(q.Var('counterVal'), 1)
    ),
    update: q.If(
      q.Equals(q.Var('counterVal'), q.Var('newCounterVal')),
      null,
      q.Update(
        q.Var('counterRef'),
        { data: { like: q.Var('newCounterVal') } }
      )
    )
  },
  q.Var('newCounterVal')
)
```

This uses `Let` to assign some named values to make it easy to re-use values. `newCounter` value is set to the incremented `counterVal` only when `counterVal` is less than 100. Updating the counter only happens when the counter actually changes (e.g. for values less than 100). The query returns the value of `newCounterVal`.

Ideally, you'd embed this query in a user-defined function (UDF). Whenever your rule to cap counts at 100 needs to change, only the UDF needs to be updated, and not every location in your application code where `100` might appear.

Comment: I ended up capping the counter functionality on the front-end in JSX - since the app is written in `NextJS` / `ReactJS`. This simplifies the `API` call. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution. I found the [FaunaDB](https://forums.fauna.com) forums build issues like this and the related. The below solution will increment the value by 1.

```
q.Update(
            q.Ref(q.Collection('Likes'), '__ref_id__'),
                {
                    data: {
                        like: q.Add(
                            q.Select(
                                ['data', 'like'],
                                q.Get(
                                    q.Ref(
                                        q.Collection('Likes'),
                                        '__ref_id__'
                                    )
                                )
                            ),
                            1
                        )
                    }
                },
            )
```

The counter button itself, written in `NextJS` / `ReactJS`, caps the functionality of the button to a `null` `onClick` for values beyond `100`.

```
<div onClick={d.data.like < 100 ? handleSubmitLikes : null}
```

`handleSubmitLikes` access the `API`.